# Get querystring in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, query-string, angular-routing

I want to get a **querystring** which is part of the actual route, this is the actual url: 
 http://localhost:13453/Vehicle/Profile/c2db202f-9bf0-4876-851c-29964484bf7a

I want to get the last value which comes after Profile/

How can I achieve that in angularJS, which I can then use to get the details like:

```
.controller('VehicleProfileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
  function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    //get the id here which I'll pass to $http call

     $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: '/Vehicle/GetProfile'
     }).
     success(function (data) {

     });

}])
```

Comment: What router are you using?  ui-router or ngRoute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a straight javascript solution, you can use something like the following without having to wire up other dependencies:

```
var loc = window.location.href; 
var id = loc.slice(loc.lastIndexOf('/'), loc.length).split('/')[1];
```

Here's a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy3qvwcy/) to play with.

Comment: I think he want to use angular in this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$stateProvider`:

```
angular.module('vehicles').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.
            state('vehiclesId', {
                url: '/Vehicle/Profile/:id',
                templateUrl: 'modules/view.client.view.html'
            });

}]);
```

than use just in controller as:

```
angular.module('vehicles').controller('VehiclesController', ['$stateParams',
function($stateParams){

       $stateParams.id

}]);
```

Comment: any where, just before the controller for example

Comment: @Laziale please try using my code, I'm sure will do the work!

Answer (score 0):

As @sma said in his comment, we would need to know what router are you using.

**ui-router**

In case you were using `ui-router` and if you defined your params in your state, you could just use `$stateParams` in order to get it in your controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
    var id = $stateParams.myParamName; // the param defined in the state
}]);
```

**ngRoute**

In case you were using `ngRoute`, you should use `$routeParams` in the same way:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$routeParams',
    function($routeParams) {
        var id = $routeParams.myParamName; // the param defined in your route
}]);
```

**EDIT**

I'm going to assume you are using `ngRoute`, so first of all, check your route definition, it should be in your `config` phase, and it should look like this:

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
}]);
```

And then, in your controller, you should be able to get your param (called `phoneId` in this example) as in the above `ngRoute` controller example (with `$routeProvider`).

Probably you should first take a look to the documentation, particulary to [this part](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

Comment: I'm not sure, where can I check the router? Is default I got when I installed from nuget. Angular is used within MVC app

Comment: Then I'll assume that you are using ngRoute, the default one. How did you define your routes/states?

Comment: I haven't defined anything specific for router/states, they are default within mvc. Do I need to check them somewhere? This is what I have in mvc code https://i.gyazo.com/96afd1ec61127d8c748b43acc6145951.png